# Как изменить цвет Ul; LI (точки)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я использовал для своего кода в начале такую команду

```
ul ::marker {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FB6D3A;
}
```

Но столкнулся с проблемой что теперь оно для всего приняло такой цвет а нужно поменять цвет в одном разделе на другой но при этом оставив этот же самый цвет. Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но для этого придётся использовать свой "маркер":

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; /* Удалить маркеры по умолчанию */
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\2022"; /* Добавляем content: \2022, он же символ точки (маркера) */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  color: red; /* меняем цвет */
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Adele</li>
  <li>Agnes</li>
  <li>Billy</li>
  <li>Bob</li>
</ul>
```

[Источник](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_bullet_color.asp)

---

Вариант с псевдоэлементом `::marker`

```css
ul li::marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Adele</li>
  <li>Agnes</li>
  <li>Billy</li>
  <li>Bob</li>
</ul>
```

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::marker)

**P.s.** ЯблокоФоны вам этого не простят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, а можно это как-то реализовать с помощью классов?

Comment: @monkeykong, да, можете допустим сделать `<ul class="list">` и потом использовать `.list > li::marker`